# File stay block until close of the program even if not used C# / Minio

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio

I try to use the Minio API to work with S3. I've spent 2 days on this problem, and i can't reach a solution.
Looking for a local upload to my Minio remote place, I tried the sample code given in MinIo SDK documentation :

```
using System;
using Minio;
using Minio.Exceptions;
using Minio.DataModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileUploader
{
    class FileUpload
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var endpoint  = "play.min.io";
            var accessKey = "Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F";
            var secretKey = "zuf+tfteSlswRu7BJ86wekitnifILbZam1KYY3TG";
            try
            {
                var minio = new MinioClient()
                                    .WithEndpoint(endpoint)
                                    .WithCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
                                    .WithSSL()
                                    .Build();
                FileUpload.Run(minio).Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // File uploader task.
        private async static Task Run(MinioClient minio)
        {
            var bucketName = "mymusic";
            var location   = "us-east-1";
            var objectName = "golden-oldies.zip";
            var filePath = "C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\golden_oldies.mp3";
            var contentType = "application/zip";

            try
            {          
                // Upload a file to bucket.
                var putObjectArgs = new PutObjectArgs()
                    .WithBucket(bucketName)
                    .WithObject(objectName)
                    .WithFileName(filePath)
                    .WithContentType(contentType);
                await minio.PutObjectAsync(putObjectArgs).ConfigureAwait(false);
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully uploaded " + objectName );
            }
            catch (MinioException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Upload Error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is their code; I took it and only change loc of my file / ids / etc...

I can't delete my file after its upload,it is blocked by the process of my program, and its the case until I totally quit it. I tried with more than one file and they all got blocked.
In my soft, I need to detele my files right after the time they are fully uploaded.
How can i achieve this ? Is is just an async misunderstanding from myself or does it come from MinIo lib ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to keep you in touch:

The code i posted worked after some runs (without any reasons / modifications), i haven't any explanation.
However, i wanted to use the sample in a more important project, and I had the same problem of file locked as described in my post (with the exact same code for the upload as shown here).
I spent a lot of time on it and could not explain why it works within a small console app and not in my more important project, even if the code is the same.

So I moved to AWS SDK; it works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue - was able to fix it by doing the Minio upload with a stream in a using block:

```
using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("someFileOnDisk", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    PutObjectArgs putObjectArgs = new PutObjectArgs()
        .WithBucket("someBucket")
        .WithObject("someFileName")
        .WithObjectSize(fileStream.Length)
        .WithStreamData(fileStream);
    await MinioClient.PutObjectAsync(putObjectArgs);
}
```